# geom_bar()で項目ラベルを2つおきに付けたい

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot2で、geom_bar()を使って棒グラフを作成しようとしています。
データは

```
            Loc season       value              label
1         Hokkaido  Start  0.65383148        Aomori_Start
2         Hokkaido    Mid  3.08996391          Aomori_Mid
3         Hokkaido    End  6.08238792          Aomori_End
4        Aomori  Start  0.82355499       Aomori_Start
5        Aomori    Mid  0.82355499         Aomori_Mid
6        Aomori    End  0.00000000         Aomori_End
…
```

のような形式で、X軸をlabel、Y軸をvalueとして棒グラフを描画して、X/Y軸を転置しています。
各バーはseasonで色分けをしています。

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = label , y = value))
p <- p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=season))+ coord_flip() + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

項目のラベルはそのままだと見にくくなりますので、2個飛ばしで地点名だけを表示させたいと考えています。
例：

```
 　　　　 - |||||(Hokkaido_Startのバー）
Hokkaido - |||||||||||(Hokkaido_Midのバー）
　　　　　- |||||(Hokkaido_Endのバー）
         - |||||||||||(Aomori_Startのバー）
Aomori   - ||||||(Aomori_Midのバー)
         - |||(Aomori_Endのバー)
```

・プロットしているものとは別な変数をラベルに表示する
・2個飛ばしで表示する
という方法がわかりませんでしたので、ご教示いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

説明とは少しずれますが、多分こういうグラフがかきたいのかなと思いました：

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Loc, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = season), position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = T))  # Legendが反転しているので直す
```

`position = "dodge"`がポイントです
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

説明に忠実にするなら：

```
df$x <- 1:nrow(df)
df$label <- ifelse(df$x %% 3 == 2, df$Loc, "")  # 2行おきにラベルをつける
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=season)) + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, nrow(df), by = 1), labels = df$label,  # ラベルをつける
                     trans = "reverse") +  # y軸が反転しているので直す
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = T))  # Legendが反転しているので直す
```